# How to convert pandas' DataFrame to DataFrame or LabeledPoint in Spark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that when working with a spark dataframe you'll want to import any data source directly as a spark dataframe. In my case I need to use pandas functions to blow out the table and create dummy variables. And so I'm using this function in my .map() function after reading in the data.

```
def parsePoint(line):
    listmp = list(line.split('\t'))
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.get_dummies(listmp[1:]).sum()).transpose()
    dataframe.insert(0, 'status', dataframe['accepted'])
    if 'NULL' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('NULL', axis=1)  
    if '' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('', axis=1)  
    if 'rejected' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('rejected', axis=1)  
    if 'accepted' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('accepted', axis=1)  
    return dataframe
```

My .reduce() function is this:

```
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint).reduce(lambda a, b: a.append(b)).fillna(0)
```

It gives me exactly what I want, but now I need to get this recombined pandas dataframe into labeledPoints so that I can use it with the MLlib algorithms. How can I do the opposite of the .toPandas() function and convert from pandas to spark dataframe or labeledPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(PANDASDATA)
```